# ArcGIS Server 10 - Feature Editing Services - Best Practices

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, feature-service

What are some best practices for editing Multi-versioned sde data through a feature service?  What should I be looking into?

EDIT: seeing that when publishing a feature service the service is published but does not show up on the rest page..but I can reference it through it's full url??  If this observation would best serve as a separate question..please advise.

Comment: If it is not showing up then you just need to refresh the rest cache.

Comment: Now to your original, I have always been against editing through a feature service.  Now in a multi-versioned sde that would only make me more nervous.

Answer (score 4):

There are some best practices listed here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Authoring_feature_services/009300000021000000/

Comment: @Justin,ah yes, but how are readers to know since your question doesn't indicate what you've already read/done to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend watching these two videos from Esri on editing:

- [Designing and Authoring Maps for Editing](http://video.esri.com/watch/665/designing-and-authoring-maps-for-editing)
- [Building Web Editing Applications with ArcGIS 10.1 for Server](http://video.esri.com/watch/1175/building-web-editing-applications-with-arcgis-10.1-for-server)